# Does the "Daedalus" actually land on the water?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

When the *Daedalus* lands at Atlantis it appears to land on the water, is there anything that's considered to be canon that proves whether the *Daedalus* is actually landing on water (and floating on the water) or whether it's landing on a submerged platform?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z4TqMZidoo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It floats. Not only can you see the Daedelus [submerged in water up to the second or third deck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMkp6r_4fdQ) in [SGA: Lost Boys](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lost_Boys) next to the pier (but not on it), we also have this quote from [SGA: Critical Mass](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Critical_Mass)

> **CADMAN:** *Flight just confirmed that the Daedalus has landed **alongside the east pier.***

Since we can see that there's nothing between the piers when the Atlantis is in space, it stands to reason that there's nothing between them when it's on water.

[image]